# python client/server to send bash command to remote machines -- osx

Tags: python, macos, bash

I'm familiar with python within the 3D application I use (OSX platform), but am struggling with its usage in a client/server relationship. I've written a simple distributed rendering script which breaks my 3D render script into smaller OSX bash shell scripts and saves them to a directory on my machine. The remote machines in the room then look at my local folder with these smaller bash shell scripts and execute them one by one until they are all gone. It is a rudimentary solution to distributed rendering, but it works. What I would like to do is have the remote machines listen for a command from my local machine (the local machine would need to send an OSX bash command to the remote machines). I have been looking and this site: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_networking.htm

This seems to be what I'm looking for, but not knowing much about how python works with the network, I'm not sure whether its secure, and I am not sure how to send a Bash command rather than a message.

If anyone has any suggestions it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at fabric. http://www.fabfile.org/

Comment: If you want to run a command on the remote machine, why not just execute it with ssh?, e.g. 'ssh remotemachine /my/dir/script.sh' You can run and monitor this with the python subprocess module.